# Protocol(SSLV3) unsupported issue while retrieving data from Splunk

Tags: maven, sdk, spring-integration, splunk

Problem/Issue: I am trying to read data from splunk in a spring application(splunk java sdk) using spring integration. I received an  error "Server chose unsupported or disabled protocol: SSLv3" while deploying the code in a TCserver.  This worked fine in local environment/builds/servers.

The current version I have for spring-integration-splunk is 1.1.0.M2. I understand that old splunk version(1.1.0) has this issue and it's fixed in latest versions. But, when I try to upgrade the spring-integration-splunk dependency with latest version(1.1.0.RELEASE), The dependency pulls splunk 1.3.0 jar which is not available in Maven. And I got this error
"Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.splunk:splunk:jar:1.3.0"

Is there an alternative or solution to this problem. (Either by adding a fix in the code or by changing the dependencies)?

Comment: i think I'll take a look today to the dependency issue and we will be happy to release Spring Integration Splunk 1.3.0 this week!

Comment: In v1.4.0 of the Splunk SDK for Java we added a workaround for this. You can see the ssl protocols example we added. Artem, let me know you if need guidance on updating the dependency - I made the change to our SDK.

Comment: Is there a way to get this dependency(v1.4.0 ) directly from maven central?

Comment: I found this group id org.apache.servicemix.bundles but doesn't seem this is from splunk?